# A way to detect a anti-cheating system

Tags: ida, disassembly, dll-injection, cheat-engine, lua

I have created a DLL for DLL inject injection to add a force feedback to a GOG game. The DLL Work perfectly. I have tried to see how work the Debug in CE with this script:

```
debugProcess()  -- Attach Debugger to the process.
function debugger_onBreakpoint()

   print("hello hacking")


    return 0 --Break

end


debug_setBreakpoint(0x542E51)
```

that work fine like I espected.

Now I have used my dll as "template" with another GOG game (DRM free) but this time after tried to hook more then 20 functions that in theory should be call but none of them trigger my code.

I have tried with CE using the previous script with the some result, the game never break.

At this point I suspect that the game could use a anti-cheating system.

For the moment I see that IDA detect the real name of many functions:

[image]

here what Cheat Engine see:

[image]

There is a way to verify if the game include a sort of anti-cheatting system or similar ?

Thank you !

Comment: Why don't you just check if the functions are really called, and not only in "theory"?

Comment: How I can check if the functions are really called ? This is what I looking for. A example can be usefull some tool that log all functions and write in a text file.